# Extracting data from multiple geogebra applets

Tags: javascript, geogebra

I am trying to build a webpage with multiple [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) applets on the same page. This works, however, I am now not able to extract the data from all the independent applets.

When I only had one applet, I could simply call

```
ggbApplet.getBase64()
```

Now, however, I have two different applets and the API does not allow me to give an ID when calling `getBase64()`, is there still a way to extract this data when having multiple applets?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the `deployggb.js` script for adding those applets. Please make sure you set different `id` parameters for both applets. This id corresponds to the name of global variable created by GeoGebra that you can use to access the applet API once it's loaded. See [an example page with two applets](https://github.com/geogebra/math-apps-examples/blob/a772606f146442017c17e02e1a4ceca61d1a6109/html/example-api-multiple.html) in the GeoGebra example repository. If you create the applets like this:

```
var applet1 = new GGBApplet({"id":"app1", "width":600,
                     "height": 600, "showToolBar": true}, '5.0');
var applet1 = new GGBApplet({"id":"app1", "width":600,
                     "height": 600, "showToolBar": true}, '5.0');
```

then you can their contents using `app1.getBase64()` and `app2.getBase64()`.